# Will my circuit get damaged fom a reverse polarity event?

Tags: usb, reverse-polarity

I have a [FE1.1S USB Hub IC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303171730_Terminus-Tech-FE1-1S-BSOP28BCN_C9359.pdf), the fe1.1S IC typically has its own 3v3 regulator but in this case an AP2213 LDO is powering the USB HUB. I would like to know if the USB hub is safe during a reverse input polarity on the USB. Although unlikely as its almost impossible to reverse the voltage on a usb host.

I am worried that a failure will occur on the VBUSM pin, since it is connected before the protection diode D1. The VBUSM pin is used to detect if a host USB is connected that The datasheet classify this pin as  ***"Schmitt Trigger Input, 5V-Tolerant"*** .

Assuming Vaux = 0V and USB is reversed polarity, the hub should have no power but in my mind there could be current from ground coming out to VBUSM. Im not really sure how a schmitt trigger is made but is it possible?

[image]

Another solution would be to place a diode right after D1, but i dont like adding the extra diode as it might introduce too much voltage drop with 2 diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZDYQPm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Normal approach for protecting the USB Vbus is a polyfuse in series, followed by a 6V TVS diode (anode to GND, cathode to the circuit side of the fuse). Any reverse voltage immediately trips the fuse, any over voltage trips the fuse. Short ESD strikes are absorbed by the TVS hopefully without tripping the fuse.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I would still need a diode for the USB to prevent Vaux(12v) can going into the usb. But i can see how a PTC+TVS combo could be a solution, i will be able to avoid doubling the diode.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I have decided to go with your solution good sir, can you recommend your preffered specs for the resettable fuse and TVS diodes? Would a Vbr = 6v alright or 5.5v better but it feels to close to 5v? If you can share your go to parts that would be greatly appreciated